# c# subtract a number from an array index in a for loop

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to find the difference of each number value in an array from an average value. I need to loop through each value and subtract each value FROM the average and display the difference. I have tried several different ways but the difference always comes out as 0 at the end. What am i doing wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace AvgNDiff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[10];
            int x = 0;
            int i;
            string entryString = "";
            int counter = 0;
            int countdown = 10;
            int sum = 0;
            int average = 0;


            while (counter < numbers.Length && numbers[x] != 10 && entryString != "0")
            {
                if (x == 0)
                    Write("Enter up to 10 numbers or type 0 to stop > ");
                else if (x == 9)
                    Write("Enter {0} more number or type 0 to stop > ", countdown);
                else
                    Write("Enter up to {0} more numbers or type 0 to stop > ", countdown);

                entryString = ReadLine();
                numbers[x] = Convert.ToInt32(entryString);


                if (entryString != "0")
                {
                    sum += numbers[x];
                    counter++;
                    x++;
                }

                countdown--;
            }

            average = sum / x;

            WriteLine("\n\nYou entered {0} numbers with a sum of {1}", x, sum);
            WriteLine("The average of your numbers is " + average);

            WriteLine("\n\nNumber       Difference");
            WriteLine("-------------------------------");



            for (i=0; i < x; i++)
            {
                int value = numbers[i];
                int diff = average-value;

                WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10}   {1,-10}", (numbers[i]), diff));
            }


            ReadKey();




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't placed "diff" as argument (instead of "value") in the very last WriteLine statement?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here

```
int value = numbers[i];
int diff = value - average;
WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10}   {1,-10}", (numbers[i]), value));
```

the key issue here is the writeline statement.

Youve told it to display `numbers[i]`, and oh wait.. `numbers[i]` (as thats what value is)

yet diff contains the variance from the average...

Comment: yes, I forgot to change it back. Post edited. Yet original results.

Comment: You also assumed average is an integer, its unlikely to be so.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> numberList = new List<int>();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter up to 10 numbers or type 0 to stop:");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int userInput = 0;

        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Only integer numbers accepted, let's try again...:");
        }

        if (userInput == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            numberList.Add(userInput);

            if (i < 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yeah, {0} more number{1} to go!", (9 - i), (i == 8 ? "" : "s"));
            }
        }
    }

    double average = numberList.Average();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("#{0}: {1} - {2} = {3}", (i+1), numberList[i], average, (numberList[i] - average));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: copy paste my code (and switch average <-> numberList[i]) and it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not cram the entire soultion into the single `Main`, extract (and debug) a method:

```
   // Subtract each item from the average
   private static double[] MyNormalize(int[] source) {
     double sum = 0.0;

     foreach (var item in source)
       sum += item;

     double[] result = new double[source.Length];

     for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i) 
       result[i] = sum / source.Length - source[i];

     return result;
   }

   ... 

   static void Main(string[] args) {
     int[] numbers = new int[10]; 

     ...
     // Input
     while (counter < numbers.Length && numbers[x] != 10 && entryString != "0") {
       ... 
       entryString = ReadLine();
       numbers[x] = Convert.ToInt32(entryString);
     }

     // Business logic
     double[] norm = MyNormalize(numbers);

     // Output
     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
       WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10}   {1,-10}", numbers[i], norm[i]));  
   }
```

Comment: Yes, true, But I am not there yet. Baby steps here.